# .onChange(of: ) for multiple @State properties at once?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way I can use `.onChange` to detect the change of multiple `@State` properties at once? I know I could just chain 2 `.onChange` modifiers but it would be better if I could just detect all at once and run some code.

```
@State private var width = 0.0
@State private var height = 0.0

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        width += 0.1
    }, label: {
        Text("Width + 0.1")
    })
    .onChange(of: width) { _ in 
        print("Changed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this case here is the simplest I think

```
.onChange(of: width + height) { _ in
    print("Changed")
}
```

**Update:** as I wrote above is 'simplest' (and for specific scenarios can be enough), but of course other variants, "more smart/heavy/generic/etc", are also available.

Thanks to @AgentBilly, here is one of them:

```
.onChange(of: [width, height]) { _ in
    print("Changed")
}
```

Comment: Super simple, thank you!

Comment: @Asperi would this still work if they both change, but the sum stays the same?

Comment: Based on what @cora mentioned, I think using an array rather than their sum would be better.

Comment: Really like the second one. In my case, I took it to the next level  `.onChange(of: [model.intValue, model.intValue2, model.boolValue ? 1 : 0] { _ in }`

Comment: I think this only works if the types are the same

Answer (score 2):

Create a struct and use that as your state:

```
struct Size {
  var width: Double = 0 
  var height: Double = 0

  // mutating func exampleMethod(){
  // }
}
```

Then init it as your state:

```
@State var size = Size()

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        size.width += 0.1
    }) {
        Text("Width + 0.1")
    }
    .onChange(of: size) { newSize in 
        print("Changed")
    }
}
```